# How can I retrieve the stored data from blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have inserted details in blockchain. When I type `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")`,

```
difficulty: 2,
extraData:     "0xd783010802846765746887676f312e372e31856c696e757800000000000000008f438649b8b4382ffd5630c744ccd6db346c8aabce2676a1fdbf752a2ce966b420bc17d8d0f5e31a1212ffad0ac36653e2df29cc14d6bb358b11512762676b0601",
gasLimit: 6382057,
gasUsed: 2653689,
hash:   "0xa3dca95fb581a30c1102732b685905ef10a454ec93e8d26171874360821c9055",
logsBloom:     "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
**number: 16,**
parentHash: "0xb9ea05ffc9908313d34a7db976e1b3017a7c9a200ace60445dc7f02d8a610795",
receiptsRoot: "0xfd5081c18fec1c7f65a80877425ac186d24713009a519e1659d2a4b2a8166c30",
sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
size: 10494,
stateRoot: "0xe62d1d87c706b650f7e984c9688dc20d1b0a5dd4a7bf05e38e56ca2e63fbfc38",
 timestamp: 1520398284,
 totalDifficulty: 33,
 transactions: ["0x93f9be64f6f5d633298957374748677498dcb57f24ecd9a1c7cf02391e786338"],
  transactionsRoot: "0xc6c6abb3365c3413fcec7ab62a73ea84d76e17b8d8d2d7c83057d477d08ffaff",
uncles: []
}
```

Its showing increase in number as and when i submit the data.

Is there any way to retrieve all the information stored in block chain. I do not want the hash and transaction details. I need the values i entered in the user interface page.

Comment: What details have you inserted into blockchain?

Comment: FirstName, LAstName, UserID etc

Comment: Do you have the contract address and source code?

Comment: I have the contract address. And source code as in the contract?

Comment: Could you explain how exactly did you put this information into blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the transaction hash, you can get the transaction. Transaction will also contain a section having `input:`. This will contain your required data, the data which was sent in that transaction

```
web3.eth.getTransaction("0x6556756757ae134....")
```

You will receive data in hex form. In order to view your data in string form, you need to convert it to string. You may use https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

You need to look into how your environment is converting solidity data in hex form and transferring it to contract. This hex data includes information of number of parameters, values of parameters, and sometimes size of parameters(in case of dynamic data).

### Example:

Lets take this example transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x584738783f4e72f49f6c08c5b1f3b7e75c897a70b0a747795294b159aebe2a08

> 0x362132ad0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006066326263376d3672326577000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003

This data can be decoded as follows:

> 0x362132ad
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d81
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
> 66326263376d3672326577000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003

If you look at the input data, you will see the first 8 characters are methodID and then the data which was sent to that address.

Comment: That will contain the BlockHAsh , contract address and all right. I need the data i entered in the block chain like the F_name, L_name etc. How can i get that values?

Comment: @Violet Pardon me, you require function `getTransaction`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: web3.eth.getTransaction() ? Any parameters ?

Comment: Yes, the transaction hash should be passed as parameter.

Comment: I am getting the some binary values in "input"

Comment: Check the updates. Copy your data and convert it to string. You can use https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter

Comment: Hi, its giving an unreadable format data

Comment: The first 8 characters denote the function you called. The things that follow are generally in blocks of 32 characters.

Comment: Will i be able to fetch the data entered and stored blockchain?

Comment: Include your input data in the question. Using that, it would be possible to get the details that you sent.

Comment: The string is in unreadable format. I am still wondering , isnt it possible to fetch and display in the terminal? I am really new at this technology. Please bear with me.

Comment: No problem, everyone is new at some point. You must have got the hex form. I am talking about the value of `input` that was displayed when you used web3.eth.getTransaction("<tx-hash>") Can you tell that data in the question?

Comment: This is the input value i got : "0xd32cf74000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000... Cannot incorporate the entire input value.

Comment: With as much data you gave, I was able to collect following information: 14, 18, 22, 26. This shows that 14 parameters were passed. Value of first 3 parameters is 18, 22, 26.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something more high-level? Like [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org), coupled with a local `testrpc` you can access data and call functions from your contract. (You can also access your contract if it's deployed in any blockchain, it doesn't need testrpc specifically)

If your contract is deployed, paste the source code in remix, compile it (`compile` tab, the `start to compile`) then access it by going in the `run` tab, paste the address of your contract in the `At Address` field, and the data and function should appear in the bottom.

Then you might need MetaMask paired with your account, once you have that choose `Injected Web3` in the `environment` field.

Comment: Hello, i am running the code in the node. So not thru testrpc

Comment: @Violet On the testnet or the main network?

Comment: i am using the ethereum private network. I am a beginner in this technology. Correct me if i am wrong. I have the used geth to connect to the network.

Comment: @Violet I'm not sure what you mean by "the private network". It's either **the** public network (main or test) or **a** private network (by definition *not public* and *not unique*). But I edited the answer to allow you to use your contact from remix.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat private networks are not necessarily the public test networks. Private network being referred here most likely is his testing environment.

Comment: I am running the user interface in a node. So i dont need testRPC. When i enter the details in the UI,   by using web3.eth.getBlock("latest"), i can see that the data is entering into the block. So the question is , is there any way to fetch the values?

Comment: @Violet Remix can work whatever network or node you're using. Can you give it a try and tell me what works and what doesn't?